# Solving a deceptively simple $u$-substitution integral

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

The integral is $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}\ dx$$

The assignment says use $u$-substitution, but I don't know what I should define $u$ as. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Ohh, I get it now! Thanks to everyone who answered!

Answer (score 2):

Start by factoring out the $\sqrt{2}$, such that your integral is:
$$I=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$
Now make the substitution:
$$u=\sqrt{x}$$
$$du=\dfrac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
Such that:
$$I=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\int du=\sqrt{2}\ u$$
And finally, substituting $x$ back:
$$\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}dx=\sqrt{2x}$$

Comment: ..why did you bother doing a substitution???

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Because we're obviously not assuming that the integral of $x^{-1/2}$ is a known result. However, it is fair to say that the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ should be. Substitution moves the problem from an integral to a derivative.

Comment: I would imagine that antidifferentiation of $x^r$ is always presented before $u$-substitution....I mean we differentiate $x^r$ using implicit differentiation...we know what to do with $\int x^r\,dx$...for rational $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=2x$.Then the integral is transformed to $\frac {1}{2} \int \frac {du}{\sqrt{u}}$ which is now easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I would use $2x = u^2$
Then you get
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2}}udu = \int du = u + C 
$$
Thus
$$
\sqrt{2x} + C 
$$